# Change script to use localhost as the mail server, port 25 or 587 online webserver

Tags: php, smtp, localhost

I been asked by the server admin to change the contact form config to localhost but I am unsure what he means by this. eveything I have search for comes up with setting up wamp or xamp this is not what I want this is on a web server.

```
<?php

    ini_set("SMTP","localhost");
    ini_set("smtp_port","465");
    ini_set('sendmail_from', 'test@hotmail.com');

    $to = 'test@hotmail.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Form';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

 ?>
```

Comment: Use phpmailer or swiftmailer? So you don't have to change any php_ini values.

Comment: What @R.CanserYanbakan means is that the mail could be sent via something else but the built-in `mail()` function, in which case changing PHP configuration is not the way to go.